# No full disk encryption in Samsung Galaxy A71

Tags: samsung, encryption, disk-encryption

I just started using my brand new Samsung Galaxy A71 (Android version 10) by doing an initial setup, and it seems it does not support full disk encryption at all. On the contrary, on Samsung Galaxy A7 it was pretty easy to enable it. As it is impossible that in 2020 mobile devices without encryption being sold, I have done a google-fu, and, weirdly, there is no indication that anyone already searched for this feature.

Where is this function hidden then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phone launched with Android 10.

In Android 10 [Full Disk Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption#full-disk) has been dropped in favor of [File Based Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption#file-based)

You no longer need to "encrypt a disk" as [everything is encrypted provided you have a lock screen with pin/fingerprint/etc. in Android 10](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd#9_9_data_storage_encryption)

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense, and now I feel stupid for not checking the _official documentation itself_. The answer is accepted after reading the linked pages. Thank you very much once again!